# Involuntary conversion of strings from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, intellij-idea

I have a .jsp file that should put a text "Français" in a browser page. The text comes from this little piece of code:

```
<%= v.getDescription() %>
```

The method returns a String that comes from a database where it is stored in UTF-8. In IntelliJ debugger the v object looks OK, but next, in the browser, the text is garbled: "FranÃ§ais", while the page is rendered as UTF-8, that is what the headers say and I checked the saved page source.
From what I see, some dark force takes my text and converts it from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 as "ç'" in UTF-8 happens to be "Ã§" in ISO-8859-1 characters.
Funny thing is that when I put out a local variable, the text comes out fine, this bit of code

```
<% String myDescription="Français"; %>
<%= myDescription %>
```

brings out "Français" nicely.
I am looking for a way where the data from v.getDescription() is passed on without further conversions as it is OK from the start.

Comment: A few questions for you.  Where does the description value come from when you're not hard coding it?  A database?  What is the default charset of your jvm?  Try starting your servlet container with the jvm option `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1`

Comment: The 'description' comes from a database where it was stored in UTF-8. I use JVM option "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding for the entire project. I mean, if you are working with an IDE, check to have UTF-8 by default.